# Load dynamically jQuery and plugin js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading jquery and a jquery plugin's js and css with a js script of mine. All scripts are called in the right order and i pay attention to their loading time (using the setTimeout func) so that plugin code is starting loaded after jquery is already there. Unfortunately the use of dollar sign in the plugin code throws the exception 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' for the dollar sign. How can i overcome this?

Comment: did you try "jQuery" instead of "$"? If not, can you show the section of code where you encounter the error?

Comment: I use jQuery instead of $ but the browser shows error when the plugin is loaded for the $ inside the plugin's js.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems i was not checking if jquery or the plugin was loaded before i load the next script etc I wrote a simple func which handles that:

```
 function checkLoad(src, nextFunc){
    if(src.readyState) 
    {
        src.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE

            if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') 
            {
                nextFunc();
            }
        };
    }
    else 
    { // Other browsers
        src.onload = nextFunc;
    }
}
```

so after loading jQuery i run this func to check its state and then the nextFunc is called which is responsible to load the plugins js etc and everyone is happy.